# android/view/View$OnUnhandleKeyListener (Error)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, toolbar

Estoy creando un menu que esta construido por un Toolbar, pero me sale un error ***android/view/View$OnUnhandleKeyListener***, tampoco consigo ver la parte del Design

Este es el codigo del **Menu**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".Principal_Activity">



    <item
        android:id="@+id/menubtn"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu"
        android:title="menulogo"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always" >

        <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/perfil"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:title="@string/perfil"
                android:visible="true" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:title="@string/logout"
                android:visible="true" />
        </menu>


    </item>


</menu>
```

Este es el codigo del **ToolBar**:

```
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logomark"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:text="PhotoGO"
        android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:fontFamily="@font/calligraffitti" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Asi se ve la parte del **Design**  del Tollbar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.julio.photogo">
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application

        android:name=".LogApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        >
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Main_Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Register_Activity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".SingIn_Activity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".Principal_Activity"></activity>

        <activity android:name=".Camera_Activity"></activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Agrega tu manifest además ya intentaste dándole a refresh donde te marca el error porque eso me lo ha solucionado a mi

Comment: Bueno le agregue al Manifest andentro de `<application>`  `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` y me trabaja. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Ok, android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"  . agi le dices que no tenga action bar recomendaria cambiarlo.